# Basic IdentityServer configuration issue

Tags: thinktecture-ident-server

I am trying to get the IdentityServer v3 AspNetIdentity example running. I downloaded it and changed the connection strings in the Host project's App.config to use my local SQL server. I didn't change anything else.

When I run the project I get this:

```
SelfHost.vshost.exe Warning: 0 : [Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Configuration.IdentityServerServiceFactory]: 18/12/2014 10:55:51 PM -- AuthorizationCodeStore not configured - falling back to InMemory
SelfHost.vshost.exe Warning: 0 : [Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Configuration.IdentityServerServiceFactory]: 18/12/2014 10:55:51 PM -- TokenHandleStore not configured - falling back to InMemory
SelfHost.vshost.exe Warning: 0 : [Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Configuration.IdentityServerServiceFactory]: 18/12/2014 10:55:51 PM -- ConsentStore not configured - falling back to InMemory
SelfHost.vshost.exe Warning: 0 : [Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Configuration.IdentityServerServiceFactory]: 18/12/2014 10:55:51 PM -- RefreshTokenStore not configured - falling back to InMemory
```

I get that it has a problem setting up required databases, but there's not much feedback on exactly what the problem is. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are warnings, not errors. The current docs explain what's mandatory and what's optional to configure: https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/configuration/serviceFactory.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. Am likely to have further, even stupider questions :)